# MNIST Tensorflow: How to manipulate a tensor of the form [i] to a tensor of a form [...0,0,0,1,0,0...] where 1 is at ith position?

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I want to transform a tensor (call it logits) of the form

```
int32 - [batch_size]
```

to a tensor (call it labels) of the form

```
 [batch_size, 10]
```

for example for batch_size=3

```
logits=[1,6,9]
labels=[[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

This question came up because I want change the cost function to a quadratic one in the tensorflow mnist example  (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist)
I use fully_connected_feed.py and in mnist.py. In mnist.py I want to change:

```
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, name='xentropy')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
```

to

```
loss= tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(logits,labels))
```

But the problem ist, that:

```
Logits tensor, float - [batch_size, 10];  
Labels tensor, int64 - [batch_size].
```

so I need to "vectorize" the labels!?
Does anyone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label "vectorization" is called one-hot encoding.

You're looking for [tf.one_hot](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#one_hot) function.

This functions takes:

1. A list of indices (your `logits` vector)
2. A `depth` parameter: that's the depth of the one-hot vector (the lenght of the one-hot encoded label)
3. `on_value` & `off_value` that you can change if you want (but defaults value of 1 and 0 are what are you looking for).
4. `dtype` thats the tensor output type.

So, you can one-hot encode your labels with:

```
one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(logits, 10, dtype=tf.uint8)
```

`one_hot_labels` is a `tf.Tensor` object.

If you need to access from python to its content, remember to eval (or run it).

Here's a toy example:

```
import tensorflow as tf.
tf.InteractiveSession()
logits=[1,6,9]
one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(logits, 10, dtype=tf.uint8)
print(one_hot_labels.eval())
```

Outputs:

```
[[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Comment: Thak you nessuno, that was exactly what I was looking for. But if I write  vectorized_labels= tf.one_hot(labels, 10) I always get TypeError: one_hot() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)
??